# how to make width of a SharePoint:FormField Textarea wider

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I would like to make the width of all the textarea in a page wider?

```
<textarea dir="none" class="ms-long" title="What?" id="WebPartManager_g_409d0371_09d6_4e84_99d3_02e694bd1a6d_ff10_new_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" cols="20" rows="10" name="WebPartManager$g_409d0371_09d6_4e84_99d3_02e694bd1a6d$ff10_new$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" style="border: 13px solid red;"></textarea>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

the easiest way to make this text field wider is to redefine the the style sheet class for .ms-long. The actual wide of ms-log as far as i remember is set to 250px.

```
.ms-long{
    width: 450px;
}
```

This can be done by SharePoint Designer.

If you just want textarea tag to be wider you need to use

```
textarea.ms-long{
    width: 450px;
}
```

For IE if it doesn't work you can try to use:
    textarea.ms-long{
        width: 450px !important;
    }
The !important in the style definition tells the browser that no other css rule is allowed to overwrite you specification.
If checked the with on lists now an they have on my server a value of 356px width.

Comment: Thanks Stefan but i need it for only textarea element.The input element also have .ms-long class.Cheers

Comment: Stefan i tried that and one of the textarea got wider in firefox but it doesn't work in IE at all.
Any ideas?

Comment: Stefan !important didn't work either.
Anyone cn help there must be a way to increase the width of the textarea boxes.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. If I understand it correctly, rich text editor is no longer rendered as an IFrame. Width is controlled by CSS style (thanks Microsoft! this is a big improvement from SP2007)

All I had to do was override the following style:

.ms-formbody .ms-rtefield
{
 width: 500px;
}

One thing to keep in mind is that MSFT has defined a min-width for RTE which is 384px in forms.css. If you want to go narrower than 384 px, you can add that property in the above class.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/efcbc1e7-2588-465b-ba7e-d9f6098ae02e/resizing-the-width-of-rich-text-editor-in-a-blog?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Credit to Difident
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/diffident/?type=forum&referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/efcbc1e7-2588-465b-ba7e-d9f6098ae02e/resizing-the-width-of-rich-text-editor-in-a-blog?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious